# What is the contents of the queue if given the following set of commands?

Tags: queue, pseudocode

```
pushQueue(‘Hello’)

pushQueue (‘Matematika’)

pushQueue (‘Komputer’)

pushQueue (‘Algoritma’)

pushQueue (‘Logika’)

for i in range(4):

    data = popQueue ()

    if (len(data) >=8):

         pushQueue (data)
```

Comment: Regarding your now deleted question, not that challenges or homework problems are welcome here. However readers expect them to come with some sort of attempt, and a statement on what specifically the poster is stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudocode is using pushQueue (are you sure you are dealing with a stack)?

Supposing it is a stack, then contents of it would be then:

Hello Matematika Komputer Algoritma

**EDIT:** given you corrected it to a queue, then its content should be:

Logika Matematika Komputer Algoritma

Here is a python code for you to try:

```
from queue import Queue 

a = Queue()
a.put("Hello")
a.put("Matematika")
a.put("Komputer")
a.put("Algoritma")
a.put("Logika")

for i in range(4):
    d = a.get();
    if len(d) >= 8:
        a.put(d)
    
while not a.empty():
    print(a.get())
```

Comment: hi, thanks to answer my question. btw, I wrote it wrong, it should dealing with a queue

Comment: Then it's contents should be: Logika
Matematika
Komputer
Algoritma